# How to store the ASCII value in a character (Ada 83 Only)

Tags: ada

How do I store the ascii value of an integer (say 33) in a character. I want something like this in Ada83, not 95

C: Code

```
char c = 10;
char *k = &c;
strncat (des, k, 1);
printf("%s",des);
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

```
C : Character := Character'Val(10);
```

or

```
C : Character := ASCII.LF;
```

The first works in all versions of Ada.  The second one was the standard way in Ada 83; it is now obsolescent.  The newer way is

```
C : Character := Ada.Characters.Latin_1.LF;
```

More information: In Ada, `Character` is an enumeration type, not an integer type.  Therefore, you can't assign an integer to it directly.  The `'Val` attribute is the Ada way to convert an integer to an enumeration;  `Enum_Type'Val(N)` means "the Nth enumeration literal defined for the enumeration type, 0-relative".  To go the other way, `Enum_Type'Pos(E)` returns the integer corresponding to the position of `E` in the enumeration list.

Comment: So it something like different bit storage size for Latin_1 and Latin_9?

Comment: No, not really.  `Character` is 8 bits, period.  The characters in the range 0..127 are the old ASCII character set, and from 128..255 the usual meaning is Latin-1.  However, they're just numbers.  If you configure an output device to tell it to use Latin-9, Latin-2, Windows-1252, or whatever, then some of the same 8-bit numbers will show up differently on your output device.  Ada has nothing to do with that.

Comment: If you want to be able to represent all characters consistently, without having to configure the output, you can use Unicode, which means using `Wide_Character` (16-bit characters) or `Wide_Wide_Character` (32-bit characters) in Ada, which _do_ use larger storage sizes.